# Getting more details in ALSA volume

Tags: configuration, alsa, music

I've bought some new speakers, and they play much louder than my old ones. It's so much that I most of the time keep them at 1% to 3% in alsamixer, which is -103dB to -84dB.

This obviously leaves little room for details in configuration. 3 options in total. What I would like is to be able to set them at 1.6% or 2.3%. Or even better: to tweak the function mapping percentages to dB, so I could make the load "area" take up less "room" in the percentage scale.

Do you by any chance know if alsa supports this level of configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `amixer` to better control the volume. But it really depends on the channel/card. For example, my card only has 255 levels, so even if I issue `amixer set PCM '0.1dB-'`, the volume is reduced by a full 0.2 dB.

Btw, it's a command line program, not graphical control. See `man amixer` or `amixer -h`.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't get absolute or relative dB setting to work, but I can use `amixer sset Master 0.1%+` and `amixer sset Master 0.1%-` to finely adjust volume.

Comment: It also seems like alsa internally uses a `playback limit` in the range 0 - 65536. 2% thus corresponds to 0.02*65536, and so it is not possible to "remap" percentages to different dB levels.